# how to extract a specific numeric string from a HTML code?

Tags: r

i am downloading some HTML element into R

```
library(RCurl)
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiejar = 'cookies.txt', followlocation = TRUE, autoreferer = TRUE, curl = curl)

html4 <- getURL('http://website/Busqueda_persona.aspx', curl = curl)
viewstate <- as.character(sub('.*id="__VIEWSTATE" value="([0-9a-zA-Z+/=]*).*', '\\1', html4))
viewstategenerator <- as.character(sub('.*id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="([0-9a-zA-Z+/=]*).*', '\\1', html4))
eventvalidation <- as.character(sub('.*id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="([0-9a-zA-Z+/=]*).*', '\\1', html4))

params <- list(
  '__VIEWSTATE' = viewstate,
  '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' = viewstategenerator,
  '__EVENTVALIDATION' = eventvalidation,
  'ctl00$cphMain$ddlTipoIdentificacion' =  "296" ,
  'ctl00$cphMain$txtNumeroIdentificacion'  = "1109927000",
  'ctl00$cphMain$ddlTipoIdentificacionPersonaACargo' = "0",
  'ctl00$cphMain$btnBuscar' = "Buscar"
  )

html5 = postForm('http://website/Busqueda_persona.aspx', .params = params, curl = curl)
```

part of the resulting `html5` includes this

```
onclick='javascript:Direccionar(1682000,296,"1109927000",1);'
```

I require to extract the `1682000` and store it into a separate element

EDIT1: after trying @akrun advise, i get this

```
sub("\\D+(\\d+).*", "\\1", html5)
[1] "3"
attr(,"Content-Type")
                charset 
"text/html"     "utf-8"
```

i have uploaded the entire `html5` R element here https://controlc.com/b9d622ff

Comment: yes. its under restricted access and requires credentials which i pass at the beginning of my script

Comment: If you have a string `str1 <- 'javascript:Direccionar(1682000,296,"1109927000",1);';sub("\\D+(\\d+).*", "\\1", str1)
[1] "1682000"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
 str_extract_all(str2, "(?<=onclick\\='javascript\\:Direccionar\\()\\d+")[[1]]
[1] "1682000" "1682000"
```

Or use in combination with `parse_number`

```
readr::parse_number(str_extract_all(str1, "onclick='javascript\\:Direccionar\\([0-9]+")[[1]])
[1] 1682000
```

There are two instance of the substring

```
> substr(str2, 51380, 51418)
[1] "onclick='javascript:Direccionar(1682000"
> substr(str2, 51536, 51574)
[1] "onclick='javascript:Direccionar(1682000"
```

It was found by `str_locate_all`

```
> str_locate_all(str2, "(?<=onclick='javascript:Direccionar\\()[0-9]+")
[[1]]
     start   end
[1,] 51412 51418
[2,] 51568 51574
```

Comment: fixing it. give me a moment please

Comment: the link is now fixed

Comment: sorry can you paste the link again as i closed that page

Comment: https://controlc.com/b9d622ff

Comment: @AndresMora can you please copy/paste that into your console.  It gives me an error `Error: unexpected '&' in "&"`

Comment: the structure looks messed up. it wont show errors but it looks like it lacks of some parenthesis. i have used `dput` to create it. i have copied exactly what i have in my console again here https://rentry.co/uxdbv

Comment: the structure that im looking is there: `onclick='javascript:Direccionar(1682000,296,\"1109927000\",1)`

Comment: still the same error, it is just that `dput` may not work in special structures.  Is there any other way to replicate it.  Without the structure, if I copy/paste only a spseciific part, not sure that works on you

Comment: one more try https://rentry.co/mirii

Comment: @AndresMora I am copy pasting with raw string i.e. `r"{yourstring}"`

Comment: @AndresMora can you try with the update.  it is working for me though

Comment: i believe the duplicated `1682377` is because there are 2 occurrences of the string? is there any way to just get one single value?

Comment: @AndresMora I think there is only a specific case, but somehow that code is giving two.  Just checking.  The update gives only a single instance though

Comment: @AndresMora I find two instances with `str_locate_all` may be there is a slight difference outside the substring you specified